# AWS SSL wildcard not working for subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, namecheap, amazon-acm

I've created SSL certificate on AWS using Certificate Manager (ACM). I included the domain and wildcard in the list of domains for this certificate:

- mydomain.com
- *.mydomain.com

Then I uploaded some application to Elastic Beanstalk. To redirect to the subdomain I added CNAME in Namecheap provider pointing from subdomain.mydomain.com to AWS app url.

The redirection works itself so I can see http://subdomain.mydomain.com but browser says it's not secure and https://subdomain.mydomain.com not working at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I had to add 443 listener to the Load balancer for the application of this domain.

Why I didn't do it?

Because I forgot that a subdomain has its own application and doesn't inherit the domain app's configuration, so all the setting should be added separately.